# ECLIPSE APPCOMPATV7 LIBRARY

Tags: android, eclipse, linker, android-appcompat

I am having trouble in connecting appcompatv7 as library.
The new eclipse neon that i've downloaded has no default appcompat in the package explorer. Now through research i've tried to place the appcompatv7 in the package explorer, placing it by using the open from file system at the file menu bar.
But i can't set it as the library for my current project. Even though it has the same location like my project. Please kindly give me tips on how to properly place the appcompatv7. The tutorials that i've search wont apply on my current situation. Since every tutorials that i've seen that the appcompatv7 is automatically created when you create a project . But in my situation its different because when i creates a project the appcompatv7 wont appear on the package explorer that gives me a huge stressful error .
I've tried cleaning but nothing happens,
when i link the appcompatv7 from using the open from file system. nothing appears on the library adding tutorial when i click the add button. Please help TIA

Answer (score 0):

Try right-clicking on your project. There should be an option like "Add support library".

Comment: I'll try to look for that dude i'll post some ss on the options for my project  later

Comment: Ive seen it and it gives me the error 'Android support Jar not found: eclipse\v4\android-support-v4.jar

Comment: It sounds to me like you don't have the support repository installed. Go to Window-> Android SDK Manager. In the window that pops up, scroll to the bottom and look for "Android Support Repository". Is that installed?

Comment: I would guess that something is corrupted with your downloaded files then. Did you ever modify the installed files or mess around with them? You might want to try uninstalling and reinstalling the support library through the sdk manager.

Comment: I would try that tnx

Comment: There is something that isn't clear here though... In the error, it says that it is missing v4. In your question, it says v7. Are you missing v4? v7? or both? I have a directory in the sdk that is sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\support-v4. Do you have something like that?

Comment: Actually, in the support-v4 folder I list above, I have a lot of subfolders for each version of the "Android SDK Build Tools " that I have installed. So you may want to try uninstalling and reinstalling those as well.

Comment: In the tools section of the sdk manager? Ive already installed all of that hough

Comment: Well i will try to install everything again and i hope its only a bug.. ill comment if anything changes

Comment: Honestly that is the only thing I can think that it would be. I have never seen that error

Comment: Dude ive seen the android-support-v4.jar and paste it on eclipse/v4/ folder that ive created since eclipse is looking for that path for the androidv4.jar now the problem that i have is the styles error

Comment: If I remember, the template inside Eclipse for creating an appcompat project isn't correct. I think the style reference needs to look like @android:style .... but I am in front of a computer. I don't remember exactly.

Comment: Is it ok that ive placed the appcompat-v7 via add from file system?

Comment: Ive tried changing the actionbaractivity to appcompatactivity as well as in the import part.

Comment: this is the errors
Asdasd\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.

Comment: how to add pictures here i really cant see an attachment option

Comment: I think you need to find an Android tutorial with appcompat for eclipse. It seems like you have multiple issues that are not linked to just missing the  library